# How to get the dynamic value of a filter input into an XSL variable?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

Is it possible to get the value of the dynamic filter input into a variable in XSL?

I need to use this variable to filter the values shown in a [DVWP](http://www.endusersharepoint.com/2009/05/08/new-article-series-laura-rogers-on-data-view-web-part-basics/).

Adding a bit more information on what exactly I am trying to do?

1. I need to have a drop down in the page. The value of the drop down should be a unique value from a field of a SharePoint list defined in the same site.
2. now when I select a particular value, this value should be available in a XSL variable.

Is it possible to do with the query string method [proposed by Ashutosh Singh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4376704/how-to-get-the-dynamic-value-of-a-filter-input-into-an-xsl-variable/4376880#4376880)?

Comment: i have followed parameter binding method mentioned by ashuntosh. created a paramter for the DVWP. Created a drop down list which was connected to a database from which drop down list gets populated. The drop down list is then binded to the DVWP parameter which goes inside the algorithm of XSL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can get it. You can use a query string or a value of some control on your page for the same.

[Filtering DVWP using a URL parameter](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointcustomization/thread/0b7d5473-f611-492e-b487-616426f4214e/).

Comment: thanks a lot for the input ashutosh. let me work on the same.

Comment: I have added a sample link which will help you out in achieving the same you have to basically create a parameter binding and would have to use it as a filter in filtering rows

Comment: i am a beginner in sharepoint. hope i will get whats parameter binding while going through the link that you have shared. thanks a ton for the prompt help :)

Comment: You can easily set the parameter binding by adding a new parameter in dvWP menu which appears by right click on the webpart and the select common control tasks

Comment: Please mark my answer as accepted if it helped - FAQ: When you have decided which answer is the most helpful to you, mark it as the accepted answer by clicking on the check box outline to the left of the answer. This lets other people know that you have received a good answer to your question. Doing this is helpful because it shows other people that you're getting value from the community. (If you don't do this, people will often politely ask you to go back and accept answers for more of your questions!)

Comment: can i use this query string method to give an user input. bacially i should have a drop down in the page where the user can select a set of value from a field in defined list. and the selected value i should get as a XSL variable. how to do the same ?

Comment: Yes you can use this you just have to attach a function on selected index changed of drop down and the query string to the URL of the page and just call the URL to open in same window.. for end user this would look like page refresh

Comment: Thanks a lot ashutosh for the time and help i was finally able to do the same using the paramter binding menthod.